# Why are the .NET LINQ methods re-written in the F# core library?

Tags: c#, linq, f#

I've seen on [github](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs) that the F# core library has a re-written set of LINQ methods. What is the reason for this? And why are they different to the C# methods?

### Edit

I'm not really sure what opinion has to do with this, but perhaps the question of why they're duplicated and why they're slightly different should be separated. An example is with the `take` method: in C# a call to take 5 elements of a 4-element sequence will return that 4-element sequence, whereas in F# it will throw an exception.

Comment: Next person to vote fore reopen please make sure to edit question to show sample of method in question inline in the post.

Comment: `Seq` module has nothing to do with Linq. LINQ is based on extension methods, `Seq` modules doesn't declare extension methods. I guess it could internally use LINQ methods, but I don't know the reason why they don't.

Comment: To summarize, `Seq` is not re-written `LINQ`.  It is actually re-written `Array` and `List`.  A possibly more interesting question is why we actually have `List.*` and `Array.*` (although the answer is not particularly interesting)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a couple of reasons why the `Seq` module contains similar functionality to LINQ:

- **F# had it first :-)** The `Seq` module in F# existed long before LINQ was added to C#. I guess the C# team might have decided to just use the `Seq` module as an implementation of LINQ, but it is not hard to see why that did not happen...
- **C# uses extension methods while F# uses functions** - in principle, F# functions are compiled as static methods, so it would not be impossible to imagine that they could be marked as extension methods accessible from C# - but it is not simple.
- **F# functions are curried** - this is tricky - in C#, the `this IEnumerable<T>` parameter is usually the first one, while in F# it is the last one (to allow partial function application)
- **F# functions take `FSharpFunc` or `Func`** - another technical difference - F# functions are compiled differently (for performance reasons)
- **Naming** is also different. For F#, this is important to keep partial OCaml compatibility.